# What is the difference between "Rajoutez à ça ..." and "Ajoutez à ça ..."?

Tags: sens, usage

> Il faut dire que Kevin Parker, pieds nus sur scène, en a bien le look avec sa barbe d’un mois et ses longs cheveux. **Rajoutez à ça** une voix plutôt haute perchée et vous ***croiriez*** entendre John Lennon dans certains enregistrements des Beatles.
>
> vs: **Ajoutez à ça** une voix plutôt haute perchée et ...

I seem to see and hear "Ajoutez à ça ..." somewhat more frequently, but I have always wondered how these two similar expressions compare?

Also... After "et", which tense is used more commonly: "croiriez" or "croirez"?

Comment: Off-topic but I always heard/read/wrote ***une voix haut perchée*** and never ***haute perchée***.

Comment: @jlliagre The same logic as "une personne haut placée", I take it?

Comment: ***Spot on  !***

Comment: @jlliagre In another instance, I would say the following: « Tu ne peux pas t'empêcher de débarquer pour **rajouter/ajouter** ton grain de sel, non ? »

Comment: In this case, I doubt "rajouter" carries the connotation of "repetition", as the idea here is that he butts into the conversation out of the blue ***for the first time***. But I do wonder, on the other hand, if "rajouter" can be interpreted as: "Other people have ***already*** voiced their respective opinions ***before you***, and now it's ***your turn*** to ***add*** your own opinion to ***theirs***"? --- Whereas with "ajouter", is it more like: "Regardless of whether other people may or may not have given their opinions, you put in yours anyway."?

Answer (score 2):

[Rajouter](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rajouter) has two main meanings.

> - Add again another instance of something already present: *Il faudrait rajouter une assiette à table.*
> - Add later something to some other thing(s): *Si tu oublie de rajouter la levure à ta pâte, elle ne lèvera pas.*

Both meanings clearly overlap and they overlap too with the simple *ajouter* so *ajouter* and *rajouter* are almost always if not always interchangeable.

In your example, *rajouter* has both meanings: add again an item to the list of characteristics, and add later a different characteristic to the list. Using *ajouter* is also possible but would slightly reduce the idea of repetition and accumulation.

About "croiriez" vs "croirez", if *rajoutez à ça* is considered a conditional clause, as it is using the present the future is the expected tense in the main clause:

> *Si vous rajoutez à ça une voix haut-perchée, vous croirez entendre...*

Should the sentence had started with the imperfect, the conditional would have been required:

> *Si vous rajoutiez à ça une voix haut-perchée, vous croiriez entendre...* *

However, the sentence is not exactly built that way, the first part is more a statement than a condition so I believe both tenses are correct.

Using the future gives certainty to the conclusion while using the conditional makes the second part more hypothetical.

Comment: « Tu ne peux pas t'empêcher de débarquer pour **rajouter** ton grain de sel, non ? » In this instance, do yo think "rajouter" carry the connotation of "accumulation", his adding his opinion to those of others (which have already been given)?

Comment: Yes, that's  what I mean when writing about repetition and accumulation.

Comment: There is still a repetition, i.e. an opinion is added again to those already expressed.

Comment: Oh, I see. Which would you use personally: "rajouter (or ajouter) ton grain de sel"?

Comment: *de rajouter ton grain de sel*

Comment: but Google NGrams only shows occurrences of *ajouter son grain de sel*...